# Kaminari and Elasticsearch NoMethodError Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, pagination, kaminari

I have one error with Kaminari and Elasticsearch on rails app. I am unable to find the problem. I think my mistake is in my controller. By the way I am using active-admin for administrate my app.

> undefined method `page' for "France":String

Elasticsearch.rb

```
case
when defined?(::Kaminari)
  Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Response.__send__ :include, Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Pagination::Kaminari
when defined?(::WillPaginate)
  Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Response.__send__ :include, Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Pagination::WillPaginate
end
```

Controller:

```
def result
  if params[:q].nil?
    @campings = []
  else
    @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search params[:q].page(params[:page]).per(14)
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're calling the `page` method on `params[:q]` which is a string. You should enclose the call to `search` with brackets so that the `page` method will be called on the result of `search` and not on `params[:q]`.

```
@campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search(params[:q]).page(params[:page]).per(14)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @nicolaswecandoit, glad that it helped :)